# Is "is close" formal enough to replace terms as "similar" , "analogous" or "comparable"?

Tags: word-usage

Is the use of the term "is close" formal enough to deal with the similarity between two concepts?

**"The term A is close to the concept of the term B".**

I need to say that two concepts are very close, but without to use the term "similar" or "analogous" or "comparable".

I would do this because such terms sound more formal than I guess that will be good for an academic issue. I'm a beginner in English, maybe I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: What would you say if I suggested you write something like this: **Term A in concept is close to term B.** The adverbial *in concept* tells the reader in what manner the term A is close to the term B.

Comment: All of the words you cite mean essentially the same thing. I have no idea what you mean by "formal enough," or why you think the other words won't work. Any of them are fine, including the phrase *close to*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you say if I suggested that you rewrite your sentence like this:

> Term A **in concept** is close to term B.

The adverbial expression *in concept* tells the reader in what manner term A is close to term B—term A is similar to term B conceptually or on the conceptual level.

Comment: Why *in concept* and not *conceptually*?

Comment: You could certainly say *conceptually*. *In concept* was the thing thing that sprang to mind.